# Importance of filenames when issuing CSR & key file for X.509 certificate

Tags: ssl

I have one confusion while generating CSR and key file.

My domain name is like `www.abc.example`

I have to run command like that on terminal:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout abc.key -out abc.csr
```

or

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout abc.example.key -out abc.example.csr
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames have no consequences on the result, you can name them whatever you want.

Even the extensions are just conventions to make human life simpler.

You just need to make sure of course that all applications using them will use their proper name.

My personal advice would be to use the full domain name in the filename, especially if you have to maintain many different certificates (in which case you may need to handle certificates for both `example.com` and `example.net` at the same time if they are two different certificates, you will need the TLD in the filename to discriminate between them).